How to solve exercise Game
Im doing a code house test on unity, using C#, where they gave me the following exercise but i wasn't able to do. but still i want to know how must be done
The exercise is:
Find the compromised server.
Rules
You are an engineer in a datacenter, and one of your servers is being hacked.
You don't know which one, but you can probe any server in the datacenter to know if its the one.
The game is played on a grid of width servers Wide and height servers high. The server on the top left corner is (0, 0). x defines the column and y defines the row.
Each turn, you are given your current position x, y and the direction to the compromised server:

(Up): the target server is above you
(Up Right): the target server is above you and on your right
(Right): the target server is on your right
(Down Right): the target server is below you and on your right
(Down): the target server is below you
(Down Left): the target server is below you and on your left
(Left): the target server is on your left
(Up Left): the target server is above you and on your left

You have to return the location of the server you want to probe as an array of 2 integers x, y, until
you find the compromised server.
To succeed your mission, you must find the server as fast as possible, before the hacker
infiltrates your network, which is represented by a maximum number of tries.
Your initial coordinates are not always (0, 0) and the initial direction is not always "DR'.
Implementation
Implement the method Solve(direction, x, y, width, height) where the parameters are:
direction: a string amongst the 8 possible directions

x: your current x
y: your current y
width: the grid width
height: the grid height

and which should return the position x,y where you want to go next, as an array of 2 integers.
Victory Conditions
You found the compromised server before the hacker infiltrated your network.
Lose Conditions

Your method retums an incorrect position.
You havent found the compromised server within the tries limit.

Constrains

1 <= width, height <= 10000

Aprox. Resolution, fails in some test:, it have some error, but i dont know where
public static int[] Solve(string direction, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    // Define the bounds for binary search
    int left = 0;
    int right = Math.Max(width, height);

    // Define the direction offsets
    int[] dx = { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1 };
    int[] dy = { -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1 };
    string[] directions = { "U", "UR", "R", "DR", "D", "DL", "L", "UL" };

    // Binary search loop
    while (left < right)
    {
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        int directionIndex = Array.IndexOf(directions, direction);
        int nx = x + mid * dx[directionIndex];
        int ny = y + mid * dy[directionIndex];

        // Check if the new position is within bounds
        if (nx >= 0 && nx < width && ny >= 0 && ny < height)
        {
            // If within bounds, continue binary search in the same direction
            left = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // If out of bounds, adjust the right bound
            right = mid;
        }
    }

    // Calculate the final position based on the binary search result
    int finalDirectionIndex = Array.IndexOf(directions, direction);
    int finalX = x + (left - 1) * dx[finalDirectionIndex];
    int finalY = y + (left - 1) * dy[finalDirectionIndex];

    return new int[] { finalX, finalY };
}

